# Matching/Aligning columns of two DFs in R

Tags: r, match

I'm having trouble matching the columns of a dataframe in R.  I need to run this line:

`rownames(clusterDF) <- rownames(OrderByCluster)`

Where the rownames of both these dfs correspond to a gene identification number. When I run this line, it overwrites the rownames of clusterDF in the same order as they are in OrderByCluster (they are in a different order).

However, the other column - the cluster number (e.g. 1, 2, 3) does not change accordingly with those rownames. That is, the cluster numbers are associated with the original rownames, not the new ones. Therefore the genes aren't being assigned to the correct cluster.

Here is what clusterDF looks like before and after changing the rownames:

e.g. Gene 20343 is meant to be in cluster 1, however after changing rownames is in cluster 2 because the column doesn't change accordingly.

[image]
[image]

For context, my OrderByCluster looks like this:

[image]

I've tried to look up what function to use, e.g. the match function but I don't think it's quite what I need? Another idea is to have rownames of clusterDF and OrderByCluster in the same order (e.g. ascending or descending), but a lot of the forum posts I've been looking at only specify how to order dfs by columns, rather than the actual rowname.

EDIT: Sorry I'm quite new to this and wasn't aware of dput. Hopefully I've done this right, but I've subsetted both clusterDF and OrderByCluster and this is the output from dput.

```
clusterDF_dput <- structure(c(2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("1", "2", "3"), class = "factor")

OrderByCluster_dput <- structure(c(9.51329554103103, 9.14277232387578, 12.2714405068735, 
10.706631872116, 8.62291428297462, 8.98952149388347, 8.52097250675874, 
12.3272001162907, 10.6044657262387, 8.45325504643134, 11.1333650918029, 
10.8998190141107, 14.3764779789928, 13.5802066640389, 10.1906849771101, 
11.1053464801885, 11.2180047488173, 13.7233369788605, 13.3576808929928, 
10.5510358229245, 12.7521453126162, 12.1288209268913, 15.1014057359463, 
13.0035983162112, 11.4248804834167, 12.7641683968991, 12.1443475666368, 
15.4920056830767, 12.8695811644779, 11.5307043114641), .Dim = 5:6, .Dimnames = list(
    c("231507", "100041546", "110257", "76933", "20343"), c("CD23_WE1", 
    "CD23_WE2", "CD23_Doc1", "CD23_Doc2", "EED_Doc1", "EED_Doc2"
    )))
```

Comment: `OrderByCluster` also has `Cluster` column?

Comment: Can you provide a small example of both the dataframe using `dput` instead of images. We cannot copy the data from an image.

Comment: Sorry for this - I've just added the dput output. Hope this helps

Comment: According to your `dput` `clusterDF_dput` is a factor which has no rownames. `rownames(clusterDF_dput)` returns `NULL` then what are you assigning to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understood the following: the rownames of both data.frames (`clusterDF` and `OrderByCluster`) are responsible for identifying the gene that are described in each row. You are trying to match the rownames of both data.frames, so you can connect correctly the information in the `OrderByCluster` table, to each gene described in `clusterDF`.

If you are trying to do this, you can actually bring all the information (all the colunms) in `OrderByCluster` table, to `clusterDF` DF by a join operation. The join operation, will pick a key that is avaliable in both tables, and will match these keys. When the join calculates all the matches, he will literally join, or blend the two tables, accordingly to these matches of these keys.

From the data you provided, the `OrderByCluster` are a matrix of numbers, and the `clusterDF` is just a vector containing factor values. In order to my code works for you, you have to transform these objects in a table (a data.frame). The code below does this transformation. Besides that, I imagine that your `clusterDF` have the rownames identifying the genes, but the `clusterDF` produced by your `dput()` output does not have these rownames, so I produced a set of random rownames, just for make the method more clear. Note that in this set of rownames, are three of the genes defined in the `OrderByCluster`, so we expect in the end, that the join will bring the information of these three genes from `OrderByCluster`.

```
OrderByCluster <- as.data.frame(OrderByCluster_dput)
clusterDF <- as.data.frame(clusterDF_dput)
row.names(clusterDF) <- c("20130", "76933", "231507", "20343", "203")
```

So, because your keys, or in other words, the values that identifies the gene's are in the rownames of your table, you need to bring these rownames, to a colunm of your table, because as rownames they are just an attribute of your objects. You can bring these rownames to a colunm of your data.frame through the `row.names()` function in conjunction with the `mutate()` function, both from `dplyr` package. I used before the `row_number()` function, but I believe that he will bring a different output from what you want.

In the example below, I am bringing these rownames to the `row_id` colunm, and then saying to the function responsible for the join (`left_join()`) that the keys in both tables are in the `row_id` colunm. So the `left_join()` function will first match the values in `row_id` colunm in both tables, an then, bring all the information in `OrderByCluster`, to the `clusterDF`, accordingly to these matches. If the `left_join()` function find no match in some line between the two tables, it will fill the line with an NA (not avaliable) value.

**Here is the code to bring the rowname to a colunm of your table**

```
library(dplyr)

clusterDF <- mutate(
  clusterDF,
  row_id = row.names(clusterDF)
)

OrderByCluster <- mutate(
  OrderByCluster,
  row_id = row.names(OrderByCluster)
)
```

**And here is the code to make the join operation**

```
clusterDF <- left_join(
  clusterDF,
  OrderByCluster,
  by = "row_id"
)
```

**Here is the result**

```
head(clusterDF)

  clusterDF_dput row_id  CD23_WE1  CD23_WE2 CD23_Doc1 CD23_Doc2 EED_Doc1
1              2  20130        NA        NA        NA        NA       NA
2              2  76933 10.706632 10.604466  13.58021  13.35768 13.00360
3              1 231507  9.513296  8.989521  11.13337  11.10535 12.75215
4              2  20343  8.622914  8.453255  10.19068  10.55104 11.42488
5              2    203        NA        NA        NA        NA       NA
  EED_Doc2
1       NA
2 12.86958
3 12.76417
4 11.53070
5       NA
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Sorry for not making it reproducible, I've included the dput output. With this method, am I still able to have clusterDF separate from OrderByCluster rather than having them merged? I need to keep them with their original dimensions if possible.

Comment: @claraina the `left_join()` is going to merge the `OrderByCluster` to the `clusterDF` table, but will not affect the number of rows of `clusterDF` or `OrderByCluster`. You still have your `OrderByCluster` intact. But now (since we are saving the result in `clusterDF`) your `clusterDF` (as I sad, will have the same number of rows) will have now all the colunms of `OrderByCluster` because you merger the two tables together. Now, if you want to keep the original tables, you can save the result of `left_join()` in another object, so you have the connection between the tables.

Comment: I'm having trouble mutating OrderByCluster (works fine for clusterDF)?

" `mutate_()` is deprecated as of dplyr 0.7.0. Please use `mutate()` instead. Error in UseMethod("mutate_") : 
no applicable method for 'mutate_' applied to an object of class "c('matrix', 'array', 'double', 'numeric')" ". I have copied and pasted the code you've provided, so I'm not sure it's reading it as mutate_

Comment: Hey @claraina, this error is happening because `mutate()` works only for data.frames. I was thinking that your objects were already data.frames. So I made edits on the answer, considering this.